# Error when calling Native Code using JNI from a Jython module

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface, jython

I am calling a simple HelloWorld program written in C from a Jython module (inside a PyDev project). There is an intermediate Java Class (in a separate Java project) which calls the native code using JNI (Java Native Interface). The native call is **successful** if I run the Java class directly. But when I call the Java class from my Jython module, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ctest in java.library.path
```

I have successfully run several C programs from my Jython module using JNA (Java Native Access). But JNA hits performance (speed) really hard and I want to revisit JNI and fix this problem (also I simply want to know what is going on). The IDE I am using is Eclipse.

Here is the code for the Java class:

```
package JNIPackage;



public class HelloWorld {

  native void helloFromC(); /* (1) */
  static {
     // Added the line below but still no luck. Was sure this would fix it. 
     System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/Users/haiderriaz/Desktop/JNI-C");
     System.loadLibrary("ctest"); /* (2) */
  }
  static public void main(String argv[]) {
     HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
     helloWorld.helloFromC(); /* (3) */
  }

}
```

Running this Java class directly, there is no error and "Hello World" gets printed out. But when I import `JNIPackage` to my Jython module and then call `JNIPackage.HelloWorld`, then all of a sudden java can not find `ctest`. I think this is strange and the problem only exists when calling C code using JNI as opposed to JNA.

Comment: JNA uses `jna.library.path` to find your `ctest` library.  `System.loadLibrary()` depends on being able to find the native library in `java.library.path`, which is derived from `%PATH%` (on windows) or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (on linux).

Comment: I tried `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "The Path");` I was sure this was gong to work but it still fails to locate the library.

Comment: Manually setting `java.library.path` won't affect the system path that was in effect when the VM was launched.  It's the system library loading path that largely determines whether `System.loadLibrary()` will be able to find a given shared library.

Comment: So , I am using Eclipse in mac. How do I get `System.loadLibrary()` to search the correct path?

Comment: Set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your JVM's environment.

Comment: I'm curious to know what performance barriers you hit with JNA, perhaps you could post to the jna-users mailing list?

Comment: @technomage. I allocate memory for several huge 1D float arrays (containing 3D images) on the java side and send them over to a C program which returns back a pointer to a float array. It seems to be slow but I will post to the JNA mailing list to see if anything can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `System.load([full path and filename of ctest])`, which works independently from values of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `java.library.path`.

To ease user configuration I usually implement my own library-search-mechanism, i.e. make it look for libraries in the working directory and on the classpath too. I know ideologically this is somewhat wrong, but works much smoother for your users. Use `java.io.File.exists` to confirm the actual location of ctest-file and then use `java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()` to get the appropriate input for `System.load`.
`System.mapLibraryName(...)` can also be useful for this.